# datetime() and SQL performance

Tags: sql, datetime, sqlite

I got a little surprised at this moment:

```
select min(t2),avg(t2),max(t2),count(t2) 
from table1 
where ts between datetime('2013-12-27 00:00') and datetime ('2014-01-04 00:00');
```

CPU Time: user **0.950000** sys 0.030000

```
select min(t2),avg(t2),max(t2),count(t2) 
from table1
where ts between '2013-12-27 00:00' and '2014-01-04 00:00';
```

CPU Time: user **0.260000** sys 0.000000

Why there is a such big time difference?
DB: SQLite3

Edit:
Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (ts datetime, t1 numeric, t2 numeric);
```

Comment: What's the type of `ts`?  Note that the use of `BETWEEN` [with date/time/timestamp types should be avoided](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), essentially anywhere you don't specify the full precision in your host variable (SQL Server just has some additional caveats, and this actually applies for all similarly referenced types).

Comment: interesting article, thank you for sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not wholly familiar with SQLite3 but from what I can see your data is stored in the standard SQL format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. When you search between a UNIX timestamp range (since `datetime` converts the Date/Time string to a timestamp), SQLite3 is probably converting each entry into a UNIX timestamp so it can check it against the conditions of your `WHERE` clause. Hence the increase in computation time.

As to why it's faster to just compare the DateTime fields without converting them into timestamps, you can see that the format is specifically `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` for a reason: it allows for easy sortability and definite comparison. I won't go into specific methodology that SQL uses, but one could easily "break down" this format by splitting the string into workable "parts"... or you could even do a literal string comparison! A timestamp conversion is **much** more tedious, and will add up when performed over many SQL entries!

An example as to how the `YYYY-MM-DD` component to a SQL DateTime works so well: Let's say I want to compare February 1st, 2014 and January 2nd, 2014. In `YYYY-MM-DD` format a string comparison would yield:

```
Feb 1 2014 > Jan 2 2014
2014-02-01 > 2014-01-02 - YYYY-MM-DD
2014-01-02 < 2014-02-01 - YYYY-DD-MM
```

As you can see, by breaking down the time units from the first of a string to the end of the string by largest to smallest order, `YYYY-MM-DD` is an excellent human-readable format for data storage.